# Polymer <dom-repeat> data binding to child element not working?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

I have a snippit as follows to try to pass a property down to a child element as follows:

```
<dom-repeat items="{{employees}}" as="employee">
  <template>
    <child-element employee={{employee}}> </child-element> 
  </template>
</dom-repeat>
```

Where employee is of type array (taken from the Polymer tutorial).

```
employees: {
   type: Array,
   notify: true,
   value() {
      return [
        {first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith'},
        {first: 'Sally', last: 'Johnson'},
      ];
    }
```

In my child element, I'm just attempting to print out the passed down property:

```
<div> <span> {{employee}} </span> </div>
```

where employee is defined as a

```
employee: {
    type: String,
    notify: true,
    value: "",
},
```

However, the values are not passed down when I try to print them out. If I change the value of employee to something else, it gets printed. Why is that? I cannot figure out why that property isn't passed down?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it does work. The problem might have been passing down the entire object to the child element. Changed to only passing the String:

```
<child-element employee={{employee.first}}> </child-element>
```